# How to format date using momentjs in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using `moment.js` in my project, what I want is to convert a date in format `dd-mm-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`. I tried this but it didn't work, it gives me an invalid date:

```
alert(moment('14/10/2017').format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the current format of your date in `moment()`:

```js
var date = moment('14/10/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
console.log(date); // 2017/10/14
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks please how can get only HH:MM from Sat Sep 23 2017 07:04:08 GMT+0100 ??

Comment: @imsiimsi `var date = moment('Sat Sep 23 2017 07:04:08 GMT+0100').format('hh:mm');`.